# Смена фона рабочего стола Python

Tags: python, windows, winapi

Пробовал:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(20, 0, "image.jpg" , 0)
```

Также пробовал:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, "image.jpg" , 0)
```

Ничего не работает, фон меняется на черный

Answer (score 0):

Пример взят [отсюда](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/10/22/pywin32-how-to-set-desktop-background/), из первого комментария

При помощи [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) попробуйте вот так:

```
from PIL import Image
import ctypes

img = Image.open("image.jpg")
img = img.tobitmap()

ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(20, 0, img , 0)
```

На десятке работает на других не проверял